# How do I assign the value from an InputBox to an outlook.folder?

Tags: vba, outlook, dialog

I found code online to hide Outlook folders. I modified it to unhide them as well.

This code brings up an InputBox which asks the user to enter the number of levels deep that their target folder is, the names of these parent folders and the name of their target folder. The code then adds all of this and generates a folder path, and then unhides the target folder... in theory!

When I manually type the folder path into the name of the outlook.folder, it works, however when I try a string generated from the InputBox, it says

> Compile Error: Type mismatch

In testing, I got VBA to print the string into an email, and then copied the manually entered folder path (the one that works) into the same email to check that they are identical (which they are).

```vb
Public Sub Test()

    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Dim PropName, Value, FolderType As String
    Dim TargetFolder As String
    Dim Lvl1 As String
    Dim Lvl2 As String
    Dim Lvl3 As String
    Dim Lvl4 As String
    Dim Lvl5 As String
    Dim FullName As String
    Dim Lvls As String
    
    Lvls = InputBox("How many levels deep are is the target folder?", "Unhide Folder")
    Select Case Lvls
        Case "1"
            Lvl1 = "Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolder" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the first level (parent) folder", "Unhide Folder") & ")"
        Case "2"
            Lvl1 = "Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolder" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the first level (parent) folder", "Unhide Folder") & ")"
            Lvl2 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the SECOND level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
        Case "3"
            Lvl1 = "Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolder" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the first level (parent) folder", "Unhide Folder") & ")"
            Lvl2 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the SECOND level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
            Lvl3 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the THIRD level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
        Case "4"
            Lvl1 = "Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolder" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the first level (parent) folder", "Unhide Folder") & ")"
            Lvl2 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the SECOND level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
            Lvl3 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the THIRD level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
            Lvl4 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the FOURTH level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
        Case "5"
            Lvl1 = "Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolder" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the first level (parent) folder", "Unhide Folder") & ")"
            Lvl2 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the SECOND level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
            Lvl3 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the THIRD level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
            Lvl4 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the FOURTH level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
            Lvl5 = ".Folders(""" & InputBox("Please enter the name of the FIFTH level folder", "Unhide Folder") & """)"
        Case Else
                
    End Select

    TargetFolder = InputBox("Please enter the name of the folder that you would like to unhide", "Unhide Folder")

    PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B"
    Value = False
    
    FullName = Lvl1 & Lvl2 & Lvl3 & Lvl4 & Lvl5 & ".Folders(""" & TargetFolder & """)"
        
    Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("[example]").Folders("[example]")        'This works great
    Set oFolder = FullName                                                                                 '... but this brings up an error
    Set oPA = oFolder.PropertyAccessor

    oPA.SetProperty PropName, Value
 
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oPA = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ask the user to pick a folder using `Application.Session.`[PickFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.pickfolder).

Your code cannot possibly work. The variable `FullName` is a string, yet you treat it as it it were as an object: `Set oFolder = FullName`. Even though string contents of the `FullName` variable looks like a VB code snippet, that does not make it such, it is still a string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *bumping users* with multiple `Input Boxes` where a spell mistake can be made you can use the `Pick Folder` dialog box in Outlook.

```
 Dim xNameSpace As NameSpace
 Dim xPickFolder As Folder
 
 On Error Resume Next
 
 Set xNameSpace = Outlook.Application.Session
 Set TargetFolder = xNameSpace.PickFolder

 If TypeName(TargetFolder) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
 
 Set xPickFolder = Nothing
 Set xNameSpace = Nothing
```

The [NameSpace.PickFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.pickfolder) method displays the `Pick Folder` dialog box. A `Folder` object that represents the folder that the user selects in the dialog box is returned back, or `Nothing` if the dialog box is canceled by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim oFolder As folder
    Dim oPA As propertyAccessor
    
    Dim PropName As String
    Dim Value As Boolean
    
    Dim TargetFolder As String
    
    Dim Lvl1 As String
    Dim Lvls As String
    
    Lvls = InputBox("How many levels deep are is the target folder?", "Unhide Folder", "1")
    
    Select Case Lvls
        Case "1"
            Lvl1 = InputBox("Please enter the name of the first level (parent) folder", "Unhide Folder", "Inbox")
            
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Case not coded"
            
    End Select

    TargetFolder = InputBox("Please enter the name of the folder that you would like to unhide", "Unhide Folder", "TestUnHide")
    
    Select Case Lvls
        Case 1
            If Lvl1 = "Inbox" Then
                Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            
            'ElseIf Lvl1 = "... " Then
                ' Set ...
            
            End If
            
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Case not coded"
            
    End Select
    
    Set oFolder = oFolder.Folders(TargetFolder)
    oFolder.Display
 
End Sub
```

A more practical solution would be to append `.Folders(TargetFolder)` to a `PickFolder`.